YA Webvisor doesn`t see css styles
I have react project, that created with create-react-app and webpack as builder (ts, sass, css modules). YA-webvisor records are displayed without css styles (project in production mode). At the same time, if I open it locally (dev mode) - the webvisor displays the records correctly and there are no problems with styles. Deleting media queries did not help, the HTML-layout and css are correct too. Any idea what might be wrong?

Check how the styles work in your html document.
My problem was that the styles were included via the <link /> tag, and Yandex-Metrica could not download these styles correctly.
When I inlined the styles into the <style>...</style> tags (yes, the html gained a bit of weight), but this helped display the styles in WebVisor.
Also, if you use webpack, check how you collect styles for dev and prod modes.
If the MinExtractCssPlugin plugin is used for Prod mode, it forms all your styles into one file and includes them in the <link> tag. If this is the case, try not using this plugin and test the behavior.
